# Inserting data into a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of people and rather than editing it in excel I would like to be able to enter data in pandas directly.

In the example table below, John has nothin in `df['Group']`

**DF**

|  | Name | ID | Grade | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 001 | 89 | Nan |
| 1 | Jane | 002 | 56 | Group 1 |
| 2 | Joan | 003 | 91 | Group 2 |
| 3 | David | 004 | 45 | Group 1 |

I'd like to be able to change this to 'Group 4', preferably without using `iloc` (it's a big-ish df).

|  | Name | ID | Grade | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 001 | 89 | Group 4 |
| 1 | Jane | 002 | 56 | Group 1 |
| 2 | Joan | 003 | 91 | Group 2 |
| 3 | David | 004 | 45 | Group 1 |

I have tried

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'John']['Group'] = 'Group 4'

df2.loc[0,'Group'] = 'Group 4'
```

These don't work (probably obvious to you).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'John','Group'] = 'Group 4'`.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'John','Group'] = 'Group 4'` if you want to do it by Name of `df.Group.fillna('Group 4',inplace=True)` if you want to fill all 'NaN's (make sure it is NaN) in Group column to be 'Group4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assigning new variables in pandas you can use either `loc` or `at` method by having name of the labels:

**`loc`** method:

```
df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'Group'] = 'Group 4'
```

**`at`** method(Caveat:**`at`** can only access a single value at a time)

```
df.at[df['name'] == 'John', 'Group'] = 'Group 4'
# **OR**
df.at[0, 'Group'] = 'Group 4'
```